# Como hacer una función que cree siempre una variable única que tenga un nombre distinto. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que una función especifica se ejecuta, se crea una nueva variable que es igual a 0, pero esa variable necesito que tenga nombres distintos, que sea un generador de variables nuevas y únicas en JavaScript

Comment: Y para que quieres eso? Cual es la finalidad?

Comment: Esto suena a un [problema X=>Y](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy). Qué tipo de problema tienes que es necesario crear variables de forma dinámica? Por qué no crear un arreglo y cada vez que la función se ejecute, se inserta un nuevo 0 en el arreglo?

Comment: En mi opinion estas haciendo overengineering, no afirmo que no se pueda, pero trabajar con un arreglo de objectos o un arreglo parece la mejor opcion